# Getting 404 in laravel 6.x

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I have created **ApiController** in **App\Http\Controllers\Api\v1**

Also created `auth` using `laravel/ui`

Default created function for front end working perfectly.

But issue is when try to call the **ApiController**

My **API Rout**e file is as below

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1', 'namespace' => 'Api\v1'], function () {
  Route::post('register', 'ApiController@register');
});
```

And my API controller look like

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api\v1;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ApiController extends Controller
{
    public function register(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'api_token' => Str::random(60),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Before 404 it was csrf error and i have resolving it by

```
protected $except = [
        '/register',
    ];
```

in **Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken**

I cant figure out two question

1. How to `except` my entire **api** call from **CSRF** using **$except..**
2. How to solve 404 for `register` method , i use postman with **POST** request and call URL `http://localhost/larablog/api/v1/register`

Comment: @Casper still getting 404

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Routes defined in the `routes/api.php` file are nested within a route group by the RouteServiceProvider. Within this group, the `/api` URI prefix is automatically applied so you do not need to manually apply it to every route in the file. You may modify the prefix and other route group options by modifying your `RouteServiceProvider` class.

1) 404 error :- Remove `api` from **prefix route**.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1', 'namespace' => 'Api\v1'], function () {
  Route::post('register', 'ApiController@register');
});
```

http://localhost/larablog/api/v1/register

#### 1. If you are using a route group:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1', 'namespace' => 'Api\v1'], function () {
  Route::post('register', 'ApiController@register');
});
```

Your `$except` array looks like:

```
protected $except = ['v1/register'];
```

#### 2. If you want to exclude all routes under v1

Your `$except` array looks like:

```
protected $except = ['v1/*'];
```

Comment: can i use `['v1/*']` ?

Comment: yes, you can check edited answer, but it'll exclude all route of v1.

Comment: i am still getting 404