# Laravel route group won't return data in API

Tags: php, laravel

If I use laravel default api route to get my logged user info it works fine:

#### Code

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/auth/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

But if I move it to my controller and place the route under group it doesn't

#### Code

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'auth', 'middleware' => ['auth:api', 'cors']], function(){
    Route::get('/user', 'API\AuthController@user');
    Route::post('/logout', 'API\AuthController@logout');
});
```

**Controller**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;
....
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function user(Request $request)
    {
      $user = $request->user();
      return response()->json($user);
    }
}
```

**Why is that?**

Comment: it may help you https://stackoverflow.com/q/58111453/6309457

Comment: @DevsiOdedra sorry but i couldn't get it, i do not have issue with my routing i know that i should call my current api like `api/auth/user` my problem is that data return as null from controller.  I even took my route out of group like `Route::get('/auth/user', 'API\AuthController@user')->middleware(['auth:api', 'cors']);` still same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved

I took out my route from group and ALSO moved my authentication routes at the top of `api.php` file now it's working fine.

Final route:

```
Route::get('auth/user', 'API\AuthController@user')->middleware(['auth:api', 'cors']);
```

Hope it help others.